# negative binomial and a poisson

Tags: probability

The number of claims received per business day at an insurers office follows a Poisson distribution with a mean of 2.4. 
Determine the probability that there are two or more days in the next five business days with three or more claims each.

I see this is a negative binomial distribution with 4 choose 1 and p^2 * q ^3 but is this correct?

Comment: Hint: A bad day has $3$ or more claims. Find the probability a day is bad (first find the probability a day is good). Call the probability a day is bad $b$. Find the probability of $2$ or more bad days. (Easier to find first the probability of $0$ or $1$ bad days.) This uses the binomial distribution with parameters $5$ and $b$.

Comment: This did not make sense at all

Comment: It was a comment, and therefore quite condensed. If tomorrow you have still not solved it, I will write out a fairly detailed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Call a day in which there are $3$ or more claims a *bad* day. We first find the probability that a day is bad.

A day is good if there are $2$ or fewer claims. By the standard formula, the probability that a day is good is $e^{-\lambda}+e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda}{1!}+e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^2}{2!}$, where $\lambda=2.4$. Thus the probability $p$ that a day is bad is given by 
$$p=1-\left(e^{-\lambda}+e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda}{1!}+e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^2}{2!}\right).\tag{1}$$
For later use, you will need to calculate $p$ explicitly using (1) with $\lambda=2.4$.

Let random variable $X$ be the number of bad days in the next $5$. Then $X$ has *Binomial distribution*, $n=5$, and $p$ the probability in (1). Thus the probability of $2$ or more bad days is
$$\binom{5}{2}p^2(1-p)^3 +\binom{5}{3}p^3(1-p)^2 +\binom{5}{4}p^4(1-p) +\binom{5}{5}p^5.$$
It is less work if we note that the probability of $2$ or more bad days is $1$ minus the probability of $0$ or $1$ bad. That gives the simpler-looking answer
$$1-\binom{5}{0}p^0(1-p)^5-\binom{5}{1}p(1-p)^4.$$